# sh random error when saving function output

Tags: shell, sh

Im trying to make a script that takes a .txt file containing lines 
like:

```
davda103:David:Davidsson:800104-1234:TNCCC_1:TDDB46 TDDB80:
```

and then sort them etc. Thats just the background my problem lies here:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
cat $1 |
while read a
do

testsak = `echo $a | cut -f 1 -d :`; <---**

echo $testsak;

done
```

Where the arrow is, when I try to run this code I get some kind of weird error.

```
+ read a
+ cut -f+ echo  1 -d :davda103:David:Davidsson:800104-1234:TNCCC_1:TDDB46
TDDB80:
+ testsak = davda103
scriptTest.sh: testsak: Det går inte att hitta
+ echo
```

(I have my linux in swedish because school -.-) Anyways that error just says that it cant find... something. Any ideas what could be causing my problem?

Comment: You can have messages in english by setting `LANG=C` before launching your script (`LANG=C ./yourscript.sh`).

Comment: You should use `$(…)` for your subcommand [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: Loosely translated, it says "Command not found" (referring to `testsak`).

Answer (score 4):

You have extra spaces around the assignment operator, remove them:

```
testsak=`echo $a | cut -f 1 -d :`; <---**
```

Answer (score 0):

The spaces around the equal sign

```
testsak = `echo $a | cut -f 1 -d :`; <---**
```

causes `bash` to interpret this as a command `testak` with arguments `=` and the result of the command substitution. Removing the spaces will fix the immediate error.

A much more efficient way to extract the value from `a` is to let `read` do it (and use input redirection instead of `cat`):

```
while IFS=: read testak the_rest; do
    echo $testak
done < "$1"
```